# MySQL Error 2003 (WAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Im tryng to learn SQL, and I installed Wamp (which includes MySQL) in Windows 7. The problem is when I open phpMyAdmin, the next error appears:

```
#1045 - Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)
```

and when I try to open the MySQL console, it request me a password (I tried root, nothing, password); when I insert it and press enter, it shows me the 2003 error (MySQL can't connect) and the console closes inmediately.

The WAMP icon is green, MySQL service is running, but it doesn't as a procces in the task manager.

I know this was asked many times, and that is a common issue, but i've been looking for the past four hours and its driving me crazy; every solution that i tried didn't work for me. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: your login credentials are wrong. that's all there is to it. reset the credentials in mysql, or set the proper ones in phpmyadmin.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but how can I do that? I just installed WAMP and is my first time with SQL, so i don't have much idea what a credential is and how can I reset it. Can you explained my a little more?

Comment: if it's a fresh install, then probably mysql's unconfigured, and the root account has NO pw.

Comment: Yes, but how can i configure it? If it has no password, why shows me an error in the console when I don't introduce any and press enter?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/postinstallation.html